# Filter objects in python, based on criteria in JSON

Tags: python, json, list, filter, list-manipulation

I have a relatively simple use case, where I need to load up the types of vehicles that fit a specific criteria. This criterion is shown in the "sample_input" variable.

Now I need to display cars that fit the correct criteria. I am reading my `car` database JSON and then creating car objects and adding them to my carDatabase list, from this list I need to select cars that fit the user's request.

So essentially what happens is this I have loaded a simple `sample_input` variable in my Main.Py

The code should do this but it doesn't (better implementations are always welcome)

Check if `Name` is empty `[]`; if it is, move on; if not, search for cars with the same name, move to the next criterion which is country of origin, check if it is empty, if it is not look for cars with the Name(s) and country of origins(s), and etc etc for the rest of criteria.

```
import json

from Vehicle import Vehicle

sample_input = {
    "Name": [],
    "country of origin": ["france", "uk"],
    "transmission": [],
    "body type": ["coupe"],
    "drive type": [],
    "doors": [],
    "fuel type": []
}


def test():
    with open("data.json") as omapper:
        data = json.load(omapper)
        Database= []
        for i in data["vehicles"]:
            name = i["Name"]
            origin = i["country of origin"]
            transmission = i["transmission"]
            bodytype = i["body type"]
            drivetype = i["drive type"]
            doors = i["doors"]
            fueltype = i["fuel type"]
            vehicle= Vehicle(name,origin,transmission,bodytype,drivetype,doors,fueltype)
            Database.append(car)

    UserOutput = []

    for vehicles in Database:
        if vehicles.origin in sample_input["country of origin"] and vehicles.body_type in sample_input["body type"] and vehicles.doors in sample_input["doors"] != "":
            print(vehicle.name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   test()
```

`Vehicle.py`: Model class

```
 class Vehicle:
        def __init__(self, name, origin, transmission, body_type, drive_type, doors, fuel_type):
            self.name = name
            self.origin = origin
            self.transmission = transmission
            self.body_type = body_type
            self.drive_type = drive_type
            self.doors = doors
            self.fuel_type = fuel_type
```

Vehicle JSON: All the vehicles my application supports.

```
  {
    "attributes": {
        "country of origin": ["japan", "america", "germany", "south korea", "italy", "sweden"],
        "transmission": ["automatic", "manual"],
        "body type": ["hatchback", "sedan", "SUV", "ute", "coupe", "convertible", "van"],
        "drive type": ["RWD", "FWD", "4WD"],
        "doors": ["4 door", "2 door"],
        "fuel type": ["petrol", "diesel", "electric", "hybrid"]
    },
    "vehicles": [
    {
        "Name": "studebaker dictator",
        "country of origin": "america",
        "transmission": "manual",
        "body type": "sedan",
        "drive type": "RWD",
        "doors": "2 door",
        "fuel type": "petrol"
    },
    {
        "Name": "mitsubishi zero",
        "country of origin": "japan",
        "transmission": "manual",
        "body type": "hatchback",
        "drive type": "FWD",
        "doors": "2 door",
        "fuel type": "petrol"
    },
   ...
    ]
    }
```

Comment: I rolled back your latest few edits because they made the answers completely impossible to relate to what you were asking. Perhaps ask a new question if you still need help.

Comment: I had to roll back again, but I edited out the products etc. Again, please don't vandalize the site by making the answers you already received incompatible with your question.

Comment: ***Again,*** I rolled back your latest edit. Chopping off the background so that "this" no longer refers to something you have already mentioned is, again, just making this confusing and unlikely to be understandable by future visitors. The purpose of Stack Overflow is as much - or more - about providing a useful resource for future visitors with the same question as it is about you getting help.

Comment: The entire problem statement is rather trivial anyway; I find it hard to imagine that anything here would be particularly a secret you need to guard. If you find something here is sensitive, you can try to obfuscate it, but probably not remove it altogether unless you also take care to refactor the rest of the question to make sense with that change, and make sure you don't remove things which are referred to or reflected in comments and answers. (And previous versions will still be visible in the edit history.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to spell out the conditions you already laid out in your prose exposition.

```py
for vehicle in Database:
    if (not sample_input["country of origin"] or vehicle.origin in sample_input["country of origin"]) and (
        not sample_input["transmission"] or vehicle.transmission in sample_input["transmission"]) and (
        not sample_input["body type"] or vehicle.body_type in sample_input["body type"]
    ):
        print(vehicle.name)
```

`not sample_input["x"]` will be `True` if `sample_input["x"]` is an empty list; if it is not, we check that `vehicle.x` is in the list.

Note also how I changed the loop variable to the singular form; we are examining one `vehicle` at a time.

If you need to be able to access each possible attribute in a loop, try something like

```py
class Vehicle:
    # ...
    def attr_map(self, label):
        """
        Map a label like 'country of origin' to
        the corresponding internal attribute,
        and return that.
        """
        return {
            'country of origin': self.origin,
            'transmission': self.transmission,
            'body type': self.body_type,
            # ... etc
        }[label]
```

and then just loop over the attributes you want:

```py
for vehicle in Database:
    vehicle_selected= True
    for attr in sample_input:
        if sample_input[attr] and vehicle.attr_map(attr) not in sample_input[attr]:
            vehicle_selected = False
            break
    if vehicle_selected:
        print(vehicle.name)
```

You could do something similar with the `i` in your JSON import loop if you wanted to; then the method to map a key to an attribute isn't necessary, and you can simply check ... `and i[attr] in sample_input[attr]`

Comment: Hi I have altered my attempt based on your suggestion, the thing is it is still not working for example when I remove all the entries and set fuel type to electric based on your logic it does not print anything,

I need it to check all the fields not just the fields that have been populated so for example 

If it is  set to fuel_type = "electric" in the JSON, the code should check name, since name is empty it means all the cars fit....it goes down the list and once it gets to "fuel_type" it will look for electric cars and stop its filter at the end of the sample_input

Comment: It will only print out the correct car if I only make the code check for "fuel type" parameter in the if statements but as I stated, I need for the code to check for the other variables too.

Comment: basically I just want one set if statement/clause/equivalent that filters based on any input provided by the user. Sorry if i was not clear

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you just kept everything as JSON until you have decided which ones you need. Then you could just loop over the key names in the `dict`. Now you need to explicitly map each input to its corresponding attribute name in the object.

Comment: Apologies, do you mind giving me a rough idea (psuedo code) on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: If you can filter at JSON import time, examine each `car` in `data["cars"]` against the `sample_input` keys. If you really need the database to be represented as objects in memory, maybe offer a method to map a field name from `sample_input` to the corresponding attribute in `self`, or just keep a reference to the original JSON `dict` as a member attribute of the object instance if you can live with having the same data repeated twice in memory.

Comment: The thing I am struggling most is how I would go about examine each car in data["cars"] with the sample_input criteria to filter. I can most likely handle the rest,if I can nail this part, would it be possible for some assistance

Comment: I tried the second method you told me about "Simply check if i[attr] is in sample_input[attr].

I have updated my attempt, if you  dont mind having a look where I went, wrong. I feel like the second method you mentioned is much easier for me to understand. Thanks so much

Comment: Since you accepted this answer, I assume you no longer need help?

Comment: Thanks I do not need any help. I had some sensitive employee infomation in the question, that has been edited to be removed (alternatively you can remove the question

Comment: Questions with upvoted answers generally cannot be deleted. If there is something specific you want removed for reasons of confidentiality, flag for moderator attention and explain what needs to be removed and why.